# Best Testing tool to test Android and iOS apps performance vs network vs webservice

Tags: android, ios, xml, web-services, performance-testing

I am trying to test my webservice vs apps vs network performance. I have 3 team who is finger pointing each other for the Bad performance of the app. Webservice team says that the XML service returns data less than half second and App is taking long time to process the XML payload. The App team says that the webservice is slow to respond and app is loading data at 1 by 10 seconds. The QA guys says that both are faster, but the net is slow. Is there any tools to test the Apps fast vs Webservice Fast vs Network.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to divide the tests before you are going to whole system performance test. 
You have verify the load on each component independently from other components. 
For example you can to develop the simple request simulator which will works against the web service. The simulator may be sets on the same LAN as the web service in order to avoid the network problems. Then you can measure the service responses stand alone. The same you can do with the App. Then if the both will work fast the network probably your problem.

The good and flexible new performance tool that I recommend is [gatlink](http://gatling.io/).

Answer (score 0):

For the app side, you could at first simply add logs in your application. One log just before the HTTP request, one just after the response, then another just before parsing your payload and one after the parsing. 
In these logs, you could write the current timestamp.